# Ruby mysql gem - How to avoid datetime automatic cast to string while querying

Tags: mysql, ruby, datetime, casting, rubygems

Is there a way to load datetime columns of MySQL database to Mysql gem's result enumarable as a Ruby datetime object (not a string type object)?

For example:

At database side we have this table with the following insert:

```
create table ContentDB.test_table
(
    id integer primary key auto_increment,
    last_update_date datetime,
    value varchar(128)
);

insert into ContentDB.test_table(last_update_date, value) values (sysdate(), 'Some test stuff..');
commit;
```

And at Ruby side, we have the following code (as a file named test.rb):

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mysql'
require 'date'

begin
    con = Mysql.new "localhost", "root", "root", "ContentDB" 
    rs = con.query "select * from test_table"
    rs.each_hash do |row|
        l_datetime_field = row['last_update_date'].strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
    end
    con.close
end
```

This gives following error:

```
test.rb:9:in `block in <main>': undefined method `strftime' for "2017-03-06 22:15:17":String (NoMethodError)
```

I know I can cast the coming "string" value explicitly to a datetime object.

But I believe, it shouldn't be the case. I want my row to be exactly the same rowtype (pl/sql jargon), i.e. each fields to be corresponding with database column types. That is to say

```
row['last_update_date']
```

must be a "datetime" data type.

Is there an implicit way to achieve this in Ruby, without using rails' ActiveRecord?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 2):

If you want more functionality than this you need to use a higher level adapter than the super basic MySQL driver. This means using [ActiveRecord](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html) or if you want something more light-weight, [Sequel](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net).

At the absolute least do not use the `mysql` gem, use the [`mysql2`](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2) gem.

The legacy `mysql` driver doesn't really understand a lot of the types in the [MySQL binary protocol](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/binary-protocol-value.html) and seems to cast them to string by default. This is a fundamental limitation of that package and is unlikely to change in the near future.

Comment: First thank you for the comment. I've just tried Sequel. Unfortunately exact same error. ActiveRecord is too heavy for my purpose (requires too much configuration as database.yml). Anyhow, thanks again for the answer.

Comment: Sequel might need to know what your schema is before casting to the right types. It has a way of defining it in a model to make your life a lot easier.

Comment: @MehmetKaplan not sure what you mean *requires to much configuration* this can be a single file that uses `ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection` (we use it all the time). The `mysql2` gem will try to type cast for you although even they state this is *"primitive"* but might be what you need. the `mysql` gem is now un-maintained so i would not expect any change as `mysql2` has basically replaced it now.

Comment: @engineersmnky, @tadman thank you both. Combination of `ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection`
and `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all` solved my issue. I'll post final code below.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @engineersmnky, @tadman for their comments under @tadman's answer, issue for me solved. The solution test code is as follows:

```
require "rubygems"
require "active_record"

begin
    con = ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(adapter: "mysql2", host: "localhost",  username: "root", password: "yeahright;-)", database: "ContentDB")
    l_sql = "select * from ContentDB.test_table"

    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all(l_sql).each do |row|
        l_datetime_field = row['last_update_date'].strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
        puts row
        puts l_datetime_field
    end
end
```

Comment: As annoying as `database.yml` can be, it's a lot less annoying than having to change your source code to change credentials when deploying. Try and keep passwords out of your code **especially** when you commit to a version control system.

Comment: Thanks @tadman, I am totally aware of the security issues. :-) These are just scripts to test.